# How to copy a button text?

Tags: javascript, button, copy, selection

I want to copy the text from a button when I click on it. I reused code from [w3 schools](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_copy_clipboard.asp). The difference with the w3 schools code is that when you click on a button it copy the text from an input, I want to copy the text from the button I'm clicking on.

```js
function copyClipboard() {
  var copyText = document.getElementById("myButton").innerHTML;
  document.execCommand("copy");
}
```

```html
<button id="myButton" onclick="copyClipboard()">Text I want to copy</button>
```

When I console.log copyText it display the text from the button but my text is never copied.

Do you know why ?

Comment: document.getElementById('myButton').innerText

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I copy to the clipboard in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/400212/how-do-i-copy-to-the-clipboard-in-javascript)

Comment: @mikeTheLiar it works if when I click on a button and it copy the text from an input, but in my case I want to copy the text from the same button I'm clicking on.

Comment: innerText not innerHtml

Comment: Top answer over there says "Don't expect clipboard related commands to work whilst you are testing code in the console. " Do you have the dev console open?

Comment: You assign the text of your button to a variable and then execute the copy command, but you haven't selected any text. You're missing that important part from the example you linked to. E.g. `copyText.select();`

Comment: It also says "`document.queryCommandEnabled('copy')` return true if the `document.execCommand('copy')` will succeed if called now." What does that method return when executed in this method?

Comment: @j08691 when I add ```copyText.select();```  it display this error : ```copyText.select is not a function```

Comment: `.select()` works for input elements like on the site you linked to, not on button html/text. My point is that you need to select the text you want copied. You aren't doing that.

Comment: @MikeTheLiar when I console.log document.execCommand('copy') it returns true and undefined.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your problem is that you are only storing the `value` of the `button`, but you are selecting nothing, so nothing will be copied to clipboard.

You need to put that content in an `input` **and select its value**  using `.select()`, so it can be copied:

```js
function copyClipboard() {
  var copyText = document.getElementById("myButton").innerHTML;
  
  var input = document.createElement("input");
  input.value = copyText;
  document.body.appendChild(input);
  input.select();
  document.execCommand("copy");
  document.body.removeChild(input); 
}
```

```html
<button id="myButton" onclick="copyClipboard()">Text I want to copy</button>
```

Comment: My bad I console.log inside my script and it display : ```<input>``` ; then if I console.log input.select() it display : ```undefined```

Comment: @NicolasTwil Check my edited code, it works if you click the button, then paste the text some where.

Answer (score 0):

I use your example, and add the function to use several bottons, like this, is working =)

> ```
> <script>
>  function copyClipboard(target) {
>     var copyText = document.getElementById(target).innerHTML;
>     //document.execCommand("copy"); --> is obsolet
>     navigator.clipboard.writeText(copyText);
>           }
> ```

```
<button onclick="copyClipboard(getAttribute('id'))" id="xxxx">123</button>
```

Answer (score -1):

```
function copyClipboard() {
    var $temp = $("<input>");
    $("body").append($temp);
    $temp.val(document.getElementById("myButton").innerHTML).select();
    document.execCommand("copy");
    $temp.remove();
}
<button id="myButton" onclick="copyClipboard()">Text I want to copy</button>
```

Comment: I want to copy the text from the button not from an input or a p :/

Comment: @NicolasTwil check my edited code, it works from a button.